# Programatic shipping and taxes with Stripe Subscription

Tags: stripe-payments

I would like to use Stripe for a physical subscription site.

- Small number of SKUs
- Some customers pick up instead of ship
- Customers whose addresses are in one state are charged state and local sales tax

I'd like to use Stripe Subscriptions to do this but shipping costs and state/local taxes will be slightly different for every single customer and but [unlike in the Stripe Orders API](https://stripe.com/docs/orders/dynamic-shipping-taxes), it does not look like Subscriptions allows for me to dynamically calculate shipping and taxes. Is my reading of this correct, or is there a way for me to programatically edit recurring shipping and taxes on a per-subscription basis?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried anything? do you have a more-specific question... currently it seems very broad

Comment: Yes, I have tried to create a test subscription manually and looked through the documentation on subscriptions to see if there is a callback for getting shipping and tax information. Most of the above is just context. I feel like "is there a way to programatically edit recurring shipping and taxes on a per-subscription bases" is very specific. It can be answered with a yes or no question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer via @mattwc in #stripe freenode: An invoice is created by the subscription each period 1 hour before it is charged. You can subscribe to this event via webhook and edit the invoice to add shipping and tax information.